# Keep image within parent that has no explicit height

Tags: css, image, flexbox, css-grid

I have a page set up as shown in the code below, with a couple of nested flexboxes. The `flex-col` div has 2 children, `header` and `content`. I would like the `content` box to take up all remaining space of the `flex-col` div, and the image inside of `content` to not be taller than that. Currently, the image fits the width properly, but just retains its aspect ratio so on different window sizes the image will extend over the footer.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nsc5w94h/1/), and here is the code:

```html
<div>
  <div class="non-footer">
    <div class="flex-col">
      <div class="header">
        Header Text
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <img class="left" src="https://dummyimage.com/400x300.png" />
        <div class="right">
          I don't care if this content overflows into the footer. The image, however, should be letterboxed (object-fit: contain).
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer">
    This is the footer area
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}

.non-footer {
  height: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.header {
  background-color: blue;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 70% 1fr;
  gap: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
}

.content .left {
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 100%; */
  object-fit: contain;
}

.content .right {
  background-color: green;
}

.footer {
  background-color: blue;
  color: aliceblue;
}
```

*Note: You can see when making the window width a lot smaller, the image fits in as is wanted. With a wider window, the image grows too big*

Is there a way to do this without an explicit height set on the `content` div?

I am aware of 2 possible solutions, which I would like to avoid if possible:

1. Set the image as a `background-image` in css and use `background-size: contain`
2. Calculate the height of the `header` and then use math to calculate the expected height of the `content` div (`non-footer height` - `header height`)